# 2dlist to kml in python

Tags: python, list, kml

Is there some way of creating a kml file from a 2d list? I'm using simplekml and trying to follow this [tutorial](http://simplekml.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tut_point.html#creating-the-code) but I keep getting an attribute error during conversion.
Does the list need to be written to a csv first and read it in?
Also, does the list need a header file or do the labels the first line in the for loop...

```
for f, i, lat, lon, n, in the2DList:
    pnt=kml.newpoint()
```

refer to the 'columns', not the actual names in the header?
There's not info found by searching... hope someone can help

Edit: example of list I have...

```
l= [['name_01','f_01_','010','-21.21','120.21', 0.9, 1.0],[name02',f_02','050',
'-21.55', 1.0,1.0][....]]
```

I'd like to include all items except first. As you can see there are also floats..

Answer (score 0):

By 2D list I assume you mean a list that only contains the latitude and longitude values, not geocoding information?

In that case, why not

```
for lat, lon in list:
    pnt = kml.newpoint ()
```

However, this is based on an assumption - please provide more information.